# wireless button not working in linux

Tags: wireless, hardware

im running gnome ubuntu 14.10/windows 7 ultimate on a hp pavilion g6 1d98dx and it appears that my wireless button is somehow bound to something to do with the softblock (not the hardblock as it should be) i ran rfkill list all and it gives me

```
 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

but if i press my wireless button (f12) nothing happens to the indicator light but when i run rfkill list all again it says

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes
```

any ideas are welcome ive tried installing diffrent distros such as mint, ubuntu, kubuntu, deepin, and fedora but they all have the same problem

Comment: @closevoters It is not a driver issue but a laptop specific block.